# android, how to build the project in order to have R.java?

Tags: android, build

I cleaned my project but after cleaning it doesn't generate R.java file. It is set to build automatically but new R file doesn't generate. Also, I disabled automatic building and manually tired to build but still don't have R file.
Also, I grated same package under gen folder and tried to build R file manually but I was not successful. Why it is like this?!!!

Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: Are there any errors in your XML resources?

Comment: Wow, how did you see my code? :)  Yes, after some changes its correct now. Thanks.

Comment: Great! I added a response so you can accept this as answered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android code wont generate R.Java after cleaing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845602/android-code-wont-generate-r-java-after-cleaing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify there are no errors in your XML resources. Any error will cause R.java not to compile.